# Debian Linux kernel versioning

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, version

On a Debian Stretch distribution, if I run `uname -a`, I obtain:

```
Linux index 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If I run `dpkg -s linux-image-amd64 | grep Version`, I obtain:

```
Version: 4.9+80+deb9u6
```

Three different kernel versions are printed by the above commands:

- 4.9.0-8
- 4.9.144-3.1
- 4.9+80+deb9u6

My question is : what are these different versions and what is their meaning?

Comment: Related: [Debian package naming convention?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/97289)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

“80+deb9u6” is the version of [the `linux-latest` source package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux-latest); this builds meta-packages which pull in the current kernel package for each platform, for example `linux-image-amd64` which you have, and are versioned with the base kernel version, resulting in 4.9+80+deb9u6.

“4.9.0-8” is the ABI version of the kernel; it appears in specific kernels’ package names, *e.g.* [`linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64). The version represents the base number of the kernel series, and a number which is bumped every time the kernel ABI changes in an incompatible way — in terms which matter to users, whenever out-of-tree modules need to be recompiled.

“4.9.144-3.1” is the package version of the kernel. This follows the standard Debian versioning scheme: 4.9.144 is the upstream kernel version, which you can match up to [upstream kernel releases](https://www.kernel.org/), and 3.1 is the version of the packaging. The first package of a given upstream version is normally given version 1 of the packaging, then every time a new package is uploaded (without changing the corresponding upstream), the packaging version is incremented. You can see the details of what changed in each version in [the Debian-specific changelog](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/l/linux/changelog-4.9.144-3.1).

All this combines to provide a number of features which are useful for end-users:

- users can install an architecture-specific meta-package, such as `linux-image-amd64`, and be sure they always have the latest available kernel package — currently the meta-package is version 4.9+80+deb9u6, which pulls in `linux-image-4.9.0-8-...`, and when the kernel version or ABI version change, a new meta-package will be uploaded;
- new upstream kernels (or Debian patches) which don’t change the kernel ABI in a backward-incompatible manner won’t result in unnecessary package churn or local rebuilds (for out-of-tree modules);
- kernel ABI changes which require them *will* result in module rebuilds, so installed modules are always available and installable into the running kernel (barring bugs).

Comment: Regarding *“80+deb9u6” is the version of the linux-latest source package*: [the *linux-latest* source package was removed in October 2019](https://ftp-master.debian.org/removals-2019.txt) ([announcement](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2019/10/msg00231.html)) ... Since then, "unsigned" versions are built from the [*linux* source package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux), and "signed" versions from their own dedicated source packages, e.g. from the [*linux-signed-amd64* source package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux-signed-amd64). ("*(un)signed*" as in "UEFI Secure Boot").