# Debian kernel version and its package version mismatch

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, package-management, deb

I'm trying to install the latest available kernel from bullseye-backports:

```
ceremcem@erik3:~$ sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports linux-image-amd64 btrfs-progs linux-headers-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
btrfs-progs is already the newest version (5.10.1-2).
linux-headers-amd64 is already the newest version (6.0.3-1~bpo11+1).
linux-image-amd64 is already the newest version (6.0.3-1~bpo11+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 224 not upgraded.
```

As it says, it seems already installed. However, the version written in the filenames are mismatch:

```
ceremcem@erik3:~$ ls /boot
config-6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64      lost+found
grub                              System.map-6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64
initrd.img-6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64  vmlinuz-6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64
```

and `uname -a` output is:

```
Linux erik3 6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1 (2022-10-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why is this mismatch? How can I install the `6.0.3` kernel as advertised?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the 6.0.3 kernel, and that is what is running, as indicated in your `uname -a` output:

> … 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1

The package names can be confusing. The names of the packages (including the version number *in the package name*) and the names of the files contained in the packages reflect the kernel ABI; the version of the kernel is indicated by the versions of the packages. See [Debian Linux kernel ABI versioning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/692596/86440) and [Debian Linux kernel versioning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/509247/86440) for details.

Comment: Third column is the actual Linux kernel version, which is `6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64`, isn't it?

Comment: No, the actual kernel version is 6.0.3-1~bpo11+1 (really, 6.0.3).

Comment: `uname -r` and `hostnamectl | grep Kernel` outputs the same string: `6.0.0-0.deb11.2-amd64`. Please see https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname, the `--kernel-release` switch. If you still insist on your interpretation, please reference some documentation.

Comment: I gave you a link to the Debian kernel handbook, isn’t that authoritative enough for you?